# Mismatch in data copy to a function argument in function call

Tags: c, casting, compilation, embedded, stack-memory

I have the below code in embedded C environment, Compiler : Hightec (Big-Endian)

```
unsigned char GlobalVar;

Func_A()
{
unsigned char var1,Retval;
var1 = 0;

retval = Func_B(0,&var1);

}


unsigned char Func_B (unsigned char val, void* ptr )
{
unsigned long localvar;

localvar = (unsigned long)GlobalVar;
*(unsigned char*)ptr  = (unsigned char)localvar;
return (0);
}
```

**Input:**
GlobalVar = 1 ,
Func_A calls Func_B.

**expected Output:**
Func_B is called, 
Second Parameter is updated with value 1.

**What I see:**
Func_B is called,
Second parameter holds value 64 (0100 0000).

**Additional comments**

```
1. Func_A is an application file.        
 2. Func_B is part of a different software module.

     3. Func_A reads the value from Func_B to do some action in application.
     4. Func_B reads the value from a global variable (it is an array) and copies it into  the second argument passed to it.
     5. The second argument is a void* because Func_B can read different global variables and finally it would typecast based on parameter 1
    (this part is not related, so i have excluded the related code)
```

What do you think is happening here ?

**EDITED**

**RE-EDITED**

**I am sorry I closed the question in a hurry**

**The problem I face here**

1. **var1** is a local variable to **FUNC_A**
2. The value gets updated in the address of **var1** in **FUNC_B**
3. When the **FUNC_B** returns, the value of **var1** is still old value.

**How I solved it**

1. I made the variable **var1** a global one.
2. I see the data

**What I suspect**

1. **var1** is a allocated in **FUNC_A**
2. **FUNC_A** calls  **FUNC_B**, the allocated space is out of scope to update the data into

What do you experts think ? I really want to know what is the root cause of this behavior ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include proper and functioning code, that doesn't give compiler errors or warnings. Preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is retval in Func_A you should use Retval.. This wouldn't compile

Comment: The "real code" is different to what you've posted , or your compiler has a bug  (probably the former)

Comment: Hi yes, The real code is different... Because i had access to only a part of it and i didnot see an apparent problem in the code, I quickly jumped in to see if there is something really nasty in the code. After i saw the full code, i could myself solve the problem

Comment: @MattMcNabb : can you check and reply ?

Comment: @DarkKnight sorry, I can't tell without real code. Your description doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned long is 4 byte length and unsigned char is 1 byte lenth. You assigned 1 byte value to 4 byte value and again assign that 4byte value to the 1byte value. There may be possibility of having junk value in the remaining 3 byte of unsigned long variable and that may be assigned(based on endianess) to your unsigned char variable.

Comment: I understand this, But don't you think the typecast (which is unsigned char) shld return the LSB irrespective of the endianess

Comment: I have edited the original question, Can you provide your inputs

Answer (score 0):

What you see : `Func_B is called, Second parameter holds value 64 (0100 0000).`

```
unsigned char Func_B (unsigned char val, void* ptr )
{
    unsigned long localvar;

    printf("val = %d\n", *(unsigned char*)ptr);
    /*HERE : val = 0*/
    localvar = (unsigned long)GlobalVar;

    *(unsigned char*)ptr  = (unsigned char)localvar;

    return (0);
}
```

What I see : From the above function, the second parameter is `void *ptr`. When I try to print the contents of it the value is as expected. `val = 0`.

@DarkKnight : `How did you check the value of the second parameter ?`

Comment: @Santhosh : I checked the value of the second variable in a debugger. Did you compile with a Big-endian platform ? GlobalVar is updated with value 1, which is copied into the second parameter

Comment: With the above mentioned code, I tried to print the same and the result is as expected. I think with debugger, it is trying to read 4 bytes. Change parameter type from `void *` to `unsigned char` and try. The output will be same

Comment: I have edited the original question, Can you provide your inputs